# Number Format Exception While Reading A File

Tags: java, parsing, parseint

Getting the following error while reading the contents of the file, I think that my code is not converting the it into integer rightly following are the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3 "
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at Program.main(Program.java:192)
```

and here is the code:

```
    FileReader fin = new FileReader("task.txt");
    BufferedReader sr = new BufferedReader (fin);
    int count = 0;
    int number = Integer.parseInt(sr.readLine());
```

Comment: Just a word of advice since it looks like you might need to read multiple lines from this file. I would suggest reading all the lines at once into an `List<String>`. See the second, very compact way of doing this provided in the top answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-to-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file/326440#326440).

Comment: Thanks @Will for your concern actually there was a space after 3 which I was neglecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to parse a String that contains a space and a digit - `"3 "`.

You should eliminate the spaces before parsing to int :

```
 int number = Integer.parseInt(sr.readLine().trim());
```

Comment: if you think that the question can be useful in some way and can help someone kindly vote up please :)